# Couldn't update Currency Exchange Rate in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, csv-import, currency-exchange-rates

I'm trying to update Currency Exchange Rate in Netsuite. I do it  with CSV import via suitescript. In loggs I could see new data and also the csv import status shows 'successfully imported'. But Currency Exchange Rate (List>Accounts>Currency Exchange Rate) list hasn't updated, it shows old values.

I want to edit this question,  later I just tried to update Exchange Currency Rate from the form by clicking 'new ' button, it saved my update but again shows old values. No idea why it behaves like this.

Comment: can you give a single line on the CSV file that you used?

Comment: I just used saved mapping for this actually. This is a line of saved map.   Base Currency,Source, Currency,Exchange Rate,Effective Date
US DOLLAR,CANADIAN DOLLAR, 1.559,1.1.1970.

Answer (score 1):

When you import an exchange rate it should have an effective date.

When you view Lists -> Accounting -> Currency Exchange Rates the list you see is the effective dates as of the date in the filter section.

You should adjust the filter to see the rates changing. Don't forget to click Refresh after changing the "As Of" date.